# Sources of Math Problems to Maintain One's "Chops"

Tags: soft-question

I got partway through a graduate degree in math and I'm now doing something "completely different," but it bothers me that my skills are fading away. I don't have a lot of time, but I would like to devote 15 - 30 minutes a day to working on a problem, or some problems.

I'm curious where you'd look for problems if you were in a similar situation...

Here are some ideas to get started:

- Martin Gardner books
- Project Euler (but do the problems without computers)
- Measurement by Paul Lockhart

I wonder about textbooks. It's hard to push oneself through textbooks outside of a class, peers, deadlines. Maybe there are some which would be friendlier than others in this regard...?

EDIT:

The 15 - 30 minutes thing is a bit arbitrary. I'm just saying I can't count on having lots of time to spend. I started reading Munkres's Topology again, and Gleason's analysis book, intending to take my time, do most of the exercises, etc..

I suppose there aren't any specific skills I'm most interested in maintaining, but I was just looking to see if you had some ideas for ways to keep my head in the game.

Comment: What skills are you concerned about sharpening?

Comment: I think Marvin is actually called Martin! (I can't make a 1-character edit to correct it, but as the post author you can.)

Comment: I do not make a habit of Project Euler problems, but I would not recommend trying to really answer them without a computer. The problems are designed with programming in mind; they are meant to be such that even getting a computer to do it requires ingenuity. So they are presumably designed to require huge computations; definitely not a 15-30 minute thing! That said, if you wanted to then you could try to think about what the best algorithm would be; but then imo you might as well implement it to make sure it works the way you want it to.

Comment: So similarly I studied math and now I am doing something that does not at all use my studies, though I did get the PhD. I use this site. It seems that when school is out, good problems are few and far between, but during the fall and spring semesters there's lots to do. I also still do my research as a hobby, with no plans of publishing unless I hit the jackpot.

Comment: Fixed that spelling blip. Thanks timtfj.

Answer (score 1):

I find that training problems for mathematical competitions are a good exercise to keep your mind sharp. For example there are

- [Training problems for the Putnam competition](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/problem_solving/putnam/training.html)
- [Questions from the ITYM](http://www.itym.org/problems)
- A list of problems considered to be standard by Arnol'd:
  [Arnold's Trivium](http://www.physics.montana.edu/avorontsov/teaching/problemoftheweek/documents/Arnold-Trivium-1991.pdf)

An exercise-rich textbook is  Atiyah's & McDonalds *Commutative Algebra*. Depending on your background their exercises might be challenging or the daily 10-15min exercise for you.

P.S.: I have been actively collecting problems involving a "trick" for a couple of years and am sure others have done so as well. Maybe you will find some of these by a google search?